# MS Excel: Fraction of date span within another date span

Tags: excel, ms-office, excel-2007, excel-formula

In Microsoft Excel 2007, given a date span, I want to find our what fraction of that date span lies within each season, which is obviously another date span.

*For example:*

> Given a span of 26 Nov 10—28 Feb 11 (95 days):
>
> > 26 Nov—30 Nov is in Spring (or Autumn for you Northerners) (5 days)
> >
> > 1 Dec—28 Feb in Summer (or Winter) (90 days)
>
> Thus, 5.3% is in Spring/Autumn and 94.7% is in Summer/Winter.

Any Excel formula to work this out?  Preferably not macro-dependent, but not a deal-breaker.

Comment: How is this datespan entered in the cell, as a text string?

Comment: @brettdj Excel-formatted date - so I assume it's technically a timestamp, but it appears as "26-Nov-11" and if edited changed to "26/11/2011"

Comment: do you already have the start and the end of the season on a table somewhere in your workbook? From your example it seems you start the winter on 1 december.

Comment: @krusaint I'm confident it will, it was correct for that date span you included, just modifying it so given a row of 100 different date spans, the formula can propagate across the row and find the answer, just a bit of rearranging of the cells and removing some "$"'s.  Thanks very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would be difficult to explain in post. I have uploaded the solution at http://www.2shared.com/file/WHU5v_h1/Book1.html Let me know if you have questions...